# java websocket forbidden 403 connection failed

Tags: spring-boot, websocket

I trying to publish the spring boot server done by mr rizky on (https://github.com/rsatrio/WebRTC-Signaling-Server)

when the server is published , i am getting 403: connection forbidden when connect through websocket from the client side.
Below are the configurations:

```
@Override 
 public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) { 

    registry.addHandler(new WebSocketHandler(), "/websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    registry.addHandler(new WebSocketHandler(), "/websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*");

}
```

gradle:

```
dependencies {
     implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
     implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:1.1.0.RELEASE'
     developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
       annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

I tried the same without setAllowedOrigins("*") but same error, any idea about how to prevent this error and how to publish it with https?

*******As an update, I tried to connect from another network, and all working fine, it seems the blockage was from the local network where the server was deployed

Answer (score 0):

As an update, I tried to connect from another network, and all working fine, it seems the blockage was from the local network where the server was deployed

Comment: You should just include this in the question description

Comment: also added in description